# What is this strange JavaScript array syntax?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I am having some trouble searching google and stackoverflow for the answer to what this piece of JavaScript code is doing:

```
obj['e'+type+fn]( window.event );
```

To me this looks like an array element with an argument/parameter:

```
array[index](argument);
```

However, I can only guess at what this is doing. Is this equivalent to:

```
array[index]=argument
```

Which is assigning an argument to the array element?

If anyone could provide a simple/generic example of what this is doing that would be great. 
I am attempting to decipher [John Resig's `addEvent()` implementation](http://ejohn.org/projects/flexible-javascript-events/). I'm not really looking for an explanation of this implementation or example related to it, but more like a dumbed-down example like [MDC has done for call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) which uses some imagined products.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
obj['e'+type+fn]( window.event );
```

This is just a way of accessing a property of an object.  For instance, if you have an object

```
a = {
 name: 'someName'
 age: 20
};
```

You can access name by using `a.name` or, as above `a['name']`.

The reason he is using the `[]` notation is so that he can build the key from multiple strings.

Thus if `type=click` and `fn=foo` he's accessing `obj.eclickfoo`.  Or `obj['eclickfoo']`

This property of the object must be a method as he's invoking it using ();  so again, he's saying:

```
obj.eclickfoo( window.event );
```

or equivalent

```
obj['eclickfoo']( window.event );
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what it is doing:

From the array `obj`, it takes the function with index `'e'+type+fn`. It then executes it passing `window.event` as a parameter.

Remember that `()` invokes a function, and `[]` extract a value from an array.

Comment: This is the same as running something like `obj.esome_typesome_function(window.event)`, except that the notation you're asking about allows you to compose the property name dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

`obj['e'+type+fn]` returns a function type. This is then executed with `window.event` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
obj['e'+type+fn]( window.event );
```

Arrays can indeed use the "obj[...]" notation, but so can any object in JavaScript. And in this case, Resig is adding the property to any object, specifically for DOM objects.

`obj['aVar']` is equivalent to `obj.aVar`. The advantage of the former is that it can also work with keywords which are reserved in JavaScript to have special meaning (e.g., obj['var'] if you defined a property called "var" on an object) and allows property names to be accessed dynamically, as in your example. Since `type` is a variable, you could not do `obj.type` since that would be finding a property exactly named "type", not finding a property with the name equal to the value of the `type` variable.

Since objects (or arrays) can hold functions as data, you can also use the invocation operator (the matching parentheses) on a function found inside of an object or array, as is done here--the property is accessed (which is a previously stored "method" or function on an object) and then invoked with the `window.event` object as a single argument.

Functions also have a built-in `toString` method on their prototype (which will get called in cases like this where you are are concatenating to a string, and therefore must want a string, as long as you don't set your own `toString` method on your function, since functions are also objects in JavaScript!). Resig's code is taking advantage of this, to define a new property, somewhat haphazardly which is normally a bad idea, but in a way which is pretty unlikely to clash with other applications also adding such a property.

So if `document.body` is the `obj` and if the `type` variable is set to "click" and "fn" is set to `function () {alert('boo!');}"`, it will actually name a property on the document.body object as "eloadfunction () {alert('boo!');}". As he explains, creating this property (and then invoking it inside his own anonymous function), allows the function to be called with the normal behavior of any "this" keyword used inside--`this` will refer to the parent object, in this case `obj`, not to a global (unless `obj` is the global--i.e., the `window` object).